# Want to change two dropdowns simultaneously with same values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to if there is any way to do that if I choose a month name in first dropdown C1, the same month gets selected in the second dropdown D1 automatically. Below is the link to my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iNNrqtG593JMph5qsLOvElQaKqGGrTtt6rsRWBTg7gg/edit?usp=sharing

[image: example]

Comment: @Marios Consider leaving the spreadsheet link as is. While  the screenshot makes the data structure clear and the question self contained, A additional link to sheet doesn't hurt the question.

Comment: @TheMaster I didn't think the link could be useful to ask such a simple question and like you said the other time public links expose the domain email of the owner. I don't think that simple question is worth the exposure and the screenshot is more than enough. But yeah, I should have kept it. We are not supposed to edit a post for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You clearly need an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger.
- The following script will set the value of `D1` with the value of `C1`
  when `C1` is **edited**.

---

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.getA1Notation()=='C1') {  
     e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.range.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it solved my problem but I want to know one more thing that if this is also possible for cells on different sheets.

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible Solution:

If you want a formula, then you can use the following in cell `D1`:

```
=C1
```

**Rundown of this formula:**

- Sets the value of `D1` to that of `C1`.